# HTML file upload "Could not create a sandbox extension" using WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, wkwebview

I'm running into a strange issue while using a WKWebView in an iOS 8 app.  The HTML page shown inside the view allows for file upload.  When images are selected, everything works fine - files are returned to the HTML/Javascript and I can then upload them.  However, if I select a video (.mov) during file selection, then it appears the WKWebView crashes.  
When this happens, the following is spit out in Xcode - "Could not create a sandbox extension for '/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0745.MOV'"

Any help would be much appreciated!  It seems strange that image files can be handed over just fine, but video breaks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Safari that crashes the browser when you try to upload videos from `<input type="file">` with "multiple" attribute set.
It was fixed in latest iOS 8.4 release, but still affects WKWebView.

*Source: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/990*

I've been studying it for at least 3 hours and came up only with these 3 solutions:

1.) **Capture/Upload single video only**

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcoder">
```

2.) **Capture/Upload single image or video**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" capture="camera,camcoder">
```

3.) **Select multiple images straight from gallery**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

First two inputs open a system popup asking if you want to capture the file, or select it from gallery. Third one will go straight to the gallery and filter only the images, so you can't select videos that would crash the app.

If anyone has a different solution, I'm all ears and willing to buy him a beer :D